# How to check for true condition in elasticsearch scripting?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with a boolean field
Say

```
 {
    "field1" : true
}
```

Now I want to check, whether the "field1" is true or not, and run a query if it is true.
How can I do that using scripts in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel's approach is superior to literally using scripts because it will be significantly faster, but if you had a need to do it within a script, then you need to check if the value *indexed* is `'T'` or `'F'` in Elasticsearch 1.x. In Elasticsearch 2.x and above, Lucene changed to using the more traditional `1` and `0`.

ES 2.x (and above):

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : [ {
        "script" : {
          "inline" : "doc['field1'].value == 1"
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

ES 1.x:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "script" : {
          "script" : "doc['field1'].value == 'T'"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's a bad idea to ever use a script unless you are required to do something that cannot be done without one, such as compare to fields simultaneously to ensure that they have the same value.

Comment: `T` and `F` don't seem working with ES2.X. You should use `1` or `0`

Comment: Good point! Lucene changed boolean to `0` / `1` in Lucene 5.x.

Comment: @pickypg : Can you pls tell me that why using script is bad ? I am using inline script for comparison based sorting. Does it have security threat like SQL injection ?

Comment: @JayShah The performance is the main reason. Running a script is always slower than using the built-in queries whenever possible. For older versions of Elasticsearch, using Groovy scripting (the default from ES 1.4 through ES 2.4) could lead to security issues (and it's slower than the new default: Painless, beginning with ES 5.0).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you wish to use a filtered query, to query only on documents where field1 is true.

If you create a filtered query, you apply a filter **before** you run a query, so you will be querying only those documents that pass your filter, you can setup a filtered query as below.

```
{
  "query":{
    "filtered":{
      "query":{
        //Your query
      },
      "filter":{
        "term":{"field1":true}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `bool` query to match a boolean condition as you want. Look at my example.

```
{
   "query" : {
      "bool" : {
         "must" : 
            {
            "term" : {
               "field1" : true
            }
         }            
      }
   }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Using a term _filter_, which is cached, is generally superior to a term _query_, which is scored. If for no other reason, the scoring is largely irrelevant for exact matches, but it _can_ make sense inside of `should` queries to _add_ to the score.